# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated on Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a custom chrome extension that has a SSO login enabled, so, for use the extension, the user has to login with the corporate accout.
The SSO login is an external URL (Microsoft login), so, for the login, when the extension start:

1. I check the login.
2. If the user if not logged, I redirect to the SSO.
3. When the SSO is loged,it callback the extension URL.
4. When the extension is supposed to reload, i receive the error "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated" and the extensio not load, see the error images:

[image]
[image]

After this, if I close the extension and open it another time, the extension works with no problem because the user is properly logged.

Comment: Check my answer here. will help you may be!!!
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006851/7418173](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68006851/7418173)

Comment: Did you find the issue with this one? On my end, it only throws an error when i'm redirecting

Comment: Sorry not, I finally use another kind of login

Answer (score 0):

to get rid of this error (crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.) I have to change the Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy in .htaccess file , found in Apache server's web folder, from "require-corp" to "cross-origin":

```
- Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "require-corp"
+ Header set Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy "cross-origin"
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).