# crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated in angular

Tags: angular, renderer

in my angular 12 code as soon as I run following:
private renderer: Renderer2,
**this.renderer.appendChild(ipsiContainer, html);**
I face crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated and my iframe is not loaded, could you please help me with that

Answer (score 3):

If you use Chrome to debugger something, and face this error,
you can try to edit Network throttling to "No throttling".

[image: Example img]

Comment: Thank you so much!
Literally after searching the whole web, your solution was the only working one.
Good job!

Comment: fixed, thanks so much !!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to launch app (`npm start`) before attaching debugger (JS Debug).

Preferably each one in it's own process.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP(Codeigniter) I faced the same error. Because of a syntax error.

Comment: it is working all other laptops, just breaking on mys system, on all browsers

Answer (score -2):

While using react i faced this problem: 
The problem is after creating the new react app, we should run the script with `npm start` command in `npm` command prompt after that the script will start and there we can see a message like compiled successfully in green colour text.
You should leave that `npm` command as it is and we should edit our react project when we reload the `localhost:3000` website, the project will perfectly work.

As a beginner and self taught developer to learn any kind of technologies at first we must know the basics we must learn them then only we can understand the complete working of our project. So keep this  mind don't close  `npm` command prompt after running your script like `npm start` then ,edit your project.
Happy hacking.