# Angular - crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. (anonymous function)

Tags: angular, intellij-idea

I'm trying to debug an Angular application in Intellij, but I got the error:"crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. (anonymous function)"

I found out this answer
[Crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated. chromewebdata/(index)꞉5305:9:5551](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67191286/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-chromewebdata-index%EA%9E%89530595551)

I can't delete launch.json, because I can't find it. I'm using Intellij.

Last test, I created new angular project and debugged it, but I got the same error.

Comment: can be a network connectivity issue; also, please make sure that you have started the server (with `ng serve`) prior to launching the debugger.Related links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67914486/crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated-in-angular, https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-crbug-1173575-non-js-module-files-deprecated

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I found out it launching the server.